# How to set oracle 19c database to be always in open mode?

Tags: oracle19c

I am using oracle 19c enterprise edition and configure a pdb by the name of orclpdb. So when I restart the computer or when it gets shutdowned after that the instance orlcpdb is not in open mode and it needs to be opened but the cdb is always in open mode. So I want that instance to be always in open mode even if I restart the pc. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: From the 'PC' reference you seem to be running Oracle on Windows; so [does this answer your question?](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntqrf/auto-starting-oracle-database-services.html)

Comment: Yes I am running oracle in windows 10

Comment: The above link didn't solve my problem. Is there another way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pluggable databases always start in `MOUNTED` mode by default. Try the following solution, with the CDB open and your PDB mounted:

```
SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb open;

SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb save state;
```

Now when you restart your instance, the pluggable database should open in `READ WRITE` mode automatically. To return it to manual startup, do the following when everything is open:

```
SQL> alter pluggable database orclpdb discard state;
```

Now the PDB will start in 'MOUNTED' mode again.